Permanent TCP/IP connections randomly disconnecting
We have a linux system (Red Hat 7.4) that occasionally disconnects a permanent TCP/IP connection to a peer device for no apparent reason. The client side code which initiates the permanent connection, will be sending and receiving data with no issues. Then suddenly it receive an async receive callback with zero bytes, indicating an EOF condition. At this point, according to standard practice, the client closes the connection. The problem is that there is no evidence of the peer closing the connection.
Wireshark traces show normal bi-directional data flow, then the client sends a FIN/ACK packet when it detects the EOF, followed by a RST/ACK, which terminates the connection. The server / peer never initiates a FIN to end the connection. It is always the client that ends the connection due to the client process receiving the EOF indication on the socket async RECV() callback.
Are there any other conditions that can cause the EOF condition to be reported back to the socket caller that are external to the client application itself?

Is the socket in non-blocking mode? If not, recv() should only return 0 when it has received a FIN packet.

And even in non-blocking mode, if there's nothing to receive it should return -1 with errno == EWOULDBLOCK

I suggest using strace() to see what is actually happening. Could there be a signal interrupting recv()?

The other way recv() can return zero is if you supply a zero length. Check that you aren't doing that.

If the TCP layer has data to send and doesn’t get any acks back for a very long time (eg several minutes) it may give up and declare the connection closed.  You can see if this happen if your client is sending data and you pull your router’s uplink cable out of the socket.

@JeremyFriesner That causes a reset, not EOS.

@Barmar - Yes, we use non-blocking mode, and I agree with your comment. Unfortunately, that is the crux of our problem. We are getting 0 bytes returned with NO FIN from the other side. We will look into trying strace().

@user207421 - We will check. We had not thought of that.

@Jeremy Friesner - The wireshark traces show normal data flow / acks.
